# pushnotification not showing when app close in marshmallow

Tags: android, push-notification, android-6.0-marshmallow

Push Notification not received when app is closed in marshmallow .when my app open its work fine. In lollipop work fine doesn't matter  app   open or close.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

i give permission  in manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to those permissions, you also need to specify a BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file with the correct intent filter:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.yourapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in your BroadcastReceiver show a notification:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
             // Show Notification
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```